# Cocoa - OpenGL ES - Wrapping my head around C-Arrays

Tags: cocoa, pointers, opengl-es, arrays

This is more of a general theory question that I just cant seem to wrap my head around, so Ill explain what Im trying to do.

Im writing a 3D Game Engine with Cocoa and OpenGL ES. Im trying to determine the best way to store my vertex data for my 3d models (each vertex has an x, y, and z position).

Previously, I was storing each vertex as an individual custom object (`AEVertex`), this object had an x, y, and z instance variable. The issue is I am using the command `glDrawArrays()`, which takes the address of a C-Array as it's first param. This C-Array is supposed to be a one-dimensional array storing all of the vert positions in succesion (vert 1's x position, vert 1's y position, vert 1's z position, vert 2's x position, vert 2's y position, vert 2's z position, etc, etc).

The issue I faced was that I had to gather all of the vertexdata for a given model from each individual vertex object and create a C-Array big enough to store all of these verts / fill the C-Array with the vert data, and then pass in this array. This is obviously going to slow things down a lot, as I am essentially allocating memory for every model twice.

So what I would LIKE to do is simply have a class AEMesh, that has a C-Array instance variable that stores all of the vertexdata for the given AEMesh object. My issue with this is that as far as I know its only possible to declare C-Array instance variables of a fixed size, however a) all of my models will have different numbers of vertices and b) I wont know how many verts each model has until reading in the model data at runtime.

So, my questions:

1. Is there some way to create a mutable, dynamic C-Array as an instance variable for an object? Thus allowing me to add new array indices for every vertex read in from a given AEMesh's model file?
2. If not, Im wondering if I can create the vertexdata C-Array outside of the AEMesh's initialization, and simply have a pointer instance variable pointing to nil when an AEMesh is instantiated, and repointed to the created C-Array after the C-Array is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you can have an instance variable that is a pointer, and use functions like `malloc` to allocate memory for it at runtime. See [this page](http://fydo.net/gamedev/dynamic-arrays) for a tutorial on dynamic arrays. And don't forget to `free` your memory later!

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the entire array part of your AEMesh class. Instead, give AEMesh an ivar that's a pointer to the vertex array. That gives you the freedom to use an array of any size, and you can replace it with a different array as often as you like.